# How to select random indices by group?

Tags: python, list, split, group-by, numpy-ndarray

I am working with the MNIST Database, where we have image pixel arrays (x_train) and corresponding image labels (y_train). How do I pick one random pixel array per digit label?

So far I am able to pick random values for x_train or y_train. However the problem is, that the selection is not considering every group once, but is random.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
from random import randint
import numpy_indexed as npi

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

labels = npi.group_by(y_train).split(y_train)
print(labels)
```

After loading the database we can group the labels. We see that we have following labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].

```
Output: 
[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8), array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8), array([2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2], dtype=uint8), array([3, 3, 3, ..., 3, 3, 3], dtype=uint8), array([4, 4, 4, ..., 4, 4, 4], dtype=uint8), array([5, 5, 5, ..., 5, 5, 5], dtype=uint8), array([6, 6, 6, ..., 6, 6, 6], dtype=uint8), array([7, 7, 7, ..., 7, 7, 7], dtype=uint8), array([8, 8, 8, ..., 8, 8, 8], dtype=uint8), array([9, 9, 9, ..., 9, 9, 9], dtype=uint8)]
```

My goal is to select 10 random indices from 10 groups and select the corresponding label and pixel array.

```
Desired Output:
Set of 10 Images: [(array([40707]), array([[[  0,   0,  ...  0,   0]]], dtype=uint8), array([6], dtype=uint8)), ...
```

In this case we would have Index: [40707], [Pixel Array], Label: [6].

So far I was not able to limit the selection of 10 random indices per label.

```
# Return a list of 10 random indices as listindex
def digit_indices_randselect():
    listi = []
    for i in range(10):
        i = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, len(y_train)), size = (1,))
        listi.append(i)
    return listi
listindex = digit_indices_randselect()
print('Random list of indices:', listindex)

# For every index in listindex return the corresponding index, pixel array and label

def array_and_label_for_digit_indices_randselect():
    listi = []
    digit_data = []
    labels = []
    for i in listindex:
        digit_array = x_train[i] #digit data (image array) is the data from index i
        label = y_train[i] #corresponding label
        listi.append(i)
        digit_data.append(digit_array)
        labels.append(label)
    list3 = list(zip(listi, digit_data, labels))
    return list3
array_and_label_for_digit_indices_randselect()
```

How can I limit the index selection per group? Or how can I split the array in a way, so I can have 10 groups to pick from and the original indices are kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will give you 10 random indexes from each group

```py
def get_random_indxs(group_value, count=10):
    train_indxs = np.arange(len(y_train), dtype=np.int32)
    group_indxs = train_indxs[y_train == group_value]
    return np.random.choice(group_indxs,count)

for group_val in np.unique(y_train):
    print(get_random_indxs(group_val))
```